# The kibana old repo can't be installed even after removing the previously installed newer version in centos 7

Tags: centos7, yum, rpm, elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed the whole elk stack 7.0 in a centos 7.0 server. I followed the following guidelines to install the kibana

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/rpm.html

But for a testing purpose I want to install kibana 6.7 in the server. So for that I want to remove the previously installed kibana 7.0 abd resinstall kibana 6.7. So inorder to do that I have used the following commands.

sudo yum remove kibana
rm -rf /usr/share/kibana
rm -rf /var/lib/kibana
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/kibana_ repo_file

An I tried to reinstall with 6.7 via the following steps

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.7/rpm.html

But when I try to yum install kibana it still try to install the previously installed kibana 7.0 version. What should I do to make it install 6.7 version or to downgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
yum --showduplicates search kibana
```

to see in which repository he finds kibana 7.0. Then you can disable or remove that repository.

Comment: @CKLZEM7 in that case please accept the answer so other people can see that the problem is solved.